# $f(c) = \alpha c$ for $f:\left[0,1\right]\longrightarrow\left[0,1\right]$ continous function

Tags: calculus, continuity

find all values of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ so for all $f:\left[0,1\right]\longrightarrow\left[0,1\right]$ that is continuous exists $c\in\left[0,1\right]$ that satisfies $f(c) = \alpha c$

Any ideas on how to find all of the possible values for $\alpha$?

Comment: You want all $\alpha$ such that for all continuous $f$ (independent of $\alpha$) there exists $c$ (dependent on $f$ and $\alpha$) with $f(c)=\alpha c$?

Comment: Exactly. but I have no idea how to do so

Answer (score 3):

- If $\alpha \geq 1$, then for every continuous function $f : [0,1]  \rightarrow [0,1]$, define $g(x)=f(x)-\alpha x$.
  Then $g(0)=f(0)-\alpha\times 0 = f(0) \geq 0$ because $f$ takes its values in $[0,1]$. Similarly, $g(1)=f(1)-\alpha \times 1 \leq f(1)-1 \leq 0$ (because $\alpha \geq 1$ and $f(1)\leq1$). So because $g$ is continuous, the intermediate value theorem can be applied, so $g$ vanishes, ie there exists $c \in [0,1]$ such that $f(c)=\alpha c$.
- If $\alpha < 1$, then for $f(x)=1$, there does not exists any $c$ such that $f(x)=\alpha c$.

Comment: Not sure I understand how you conclude from $g(0) \geq 0$ and $g(1) \leq 1$ that $g$ has a zero.

Comment: Ok, let me edit :)

Comment: Perhaps you mean $g(1) \le 0$, as $f(1) \le 1$ and $-\alpha \le -1$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was a typo ! I guess it is better now ?